# How can I visualize $c\mathbf{v} + (1 - c)\mathbf{w}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Draw the line of all combinations that has $c\mathbf{v} + d\mathbf{w}$ and $c + d = 1$.
>
> **Solution:** All combinations with $c + d = 1$ are on the line that passes through $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{w}$.

[image] [image] [image]

1. $c\mathbf{v} + d\mathbf{w} \quad \& \quad  c + d = 1 \implies c\mathbf{v} + (1 - c)\mathbf{w}$.
   But how do I draw $(1 - c)\mathbf{w}$?
2. My $c = 1.5$ sketch fits the solution. But why doesn't my sketch for $c = -0.5$?

I additionally tried $c\mathbf{v} + (1 - c)\mathbf{w} = \color{#318CE7}{c(\mathbf{v} - \mathbf{w}) + \mathbf{w}} $ in picture 2 but it doesn't agree with solution?

3. How can I get the solution algebraically,  without pictures?

Comment: I think in picture 2 if you shifted the initial point of c(v-w) to origin then your observation will agree with the result..

Comment: And for $c=-0.5$, start $-0.5v$ from origin...

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $AB$ and $AC$ are your vectors $v$ and $w$, respectively. Then $AD$ is your convex combination $uv+(1-u)w$, where $uv$ is $AF$, and $AE$ is $(1-u)w$. The similarities between the triangles $BFD$, $EDC$ and $ABC$ explains it.

The fact that $BD+DC=BC$ is related to $(1-u)+u=1$, because you get $BD/BC+DC/BC=1$. Now, the triangles similarities gives you that $BD/BC=FD/AC=AE/AC=1-u$ and $DC/BC=ED/AB=AF/AB=u$.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this little illustration will help too (sorry for the quality). The problem in issue#2 is the wrong addition of vectors.

[image]